# aura:locationChange doesn't work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have the following lightning component, `TestUrlChange`:

**TestUrlChange.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="hash" type="String" />
    <aura:handler event="aura:locationChange" action="{!c.locationChange}" />

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div>{!v.hash}</div>
</aura:component>
```

**TestUrlChangeController.js**

```
({
    locationChange: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.hash", event.getParam('token'));
    }
})
```

... and a **TestApp.app** just in case.

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:TestUrlChange />
</aura:application>
```

Above code works just fine in Chrome.

[image: Chrome]

But in IE11, the handler isn't invoked.[image]

Comment: Known Issue from SFDC: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001ChxQAE&title=lightning-component-event-aura-locationchange-navigation-when-switching-apps-differs-between-ie11-and-chrome